# Using library for convert date

Tags: php, html, date, datetime

I am using a library for converting `Gregorian date` to my country's date.

Following code is an example of my coding :

```
Include_once("jdf.php");
$test_date = "2018-09-09 06:00:00";
$changed_date = jdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($test_date));
echo $changed_date;
```

But when I use this for database rows, just Y-m-d become convert.
Following code is my script:

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT date as table_date FROM api_table;");
    $stmt->execute();
    Include("jdf.php");
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            $convert_date = jdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($table_date));
            echo $convert_date;
        }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can you help me guys ??

Comment: What output do you expect to get and what output do you actually get?

Comment: Also, what datatype is the ´date´ column in api_table?

Comment: @FabianGillenius date type is `datatime` and output just convert the first row's H:i:s and convert all rows Y/m/d

Comment: Is the date stored inside the database identical to the $test_date? If you echo both strtotime(), do you get the same result?

Comment: @FabianGillenius This is saved time in database: 2018-09-06 08:13:24.700412 
and if I remove `strtotime()` I will get this error: `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

Comment: @FabianGillenius i works for first row but not for other rows

Comment: @FabianGillenius I have converted Y-m-d for all rows

Comment: In the second example you use the format Y/m/d instead of Y-m-d. This shouldn't make a difference, but I'm not familiar with the library you're using. What happens if you change the second example to Y-m-d?

Comment: @FabianGillenius Does not matter. my friend my problem is about H:i:s no Y-m-d, Y-m-d convert successful but my script just converts H:i:s for the first record.

Comment: I realize that, but sometimes the error stems from a section of otherwise functioning code. I see no errors in your code. Would you mind sharing a link to the library you are using?

Comment: @FabianGillenius https://jdf.scr.ir/download/jdf_dl.php

Comment: The only difference I can see apart from the format is the precision. In the interest of ruling out any weird behavioral bugs, would you mind trying the following? After extract($row); do this:
$new_date = explode('.', $table_date);
$convert_date = jdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($new_date[0]));

Comment: @FabianGillenius Does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set timezone :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
```